# What is the difference while writing using Python and Redis

Tags: python, redis

When I am trying to write to a file using Python, i am getting IO error, but when trying to write same data to redis, i am not getting any error, could you let me know what will be the differences with both of them? If both are writing with same data, both should give error or both should work, but why one is working and another is failing

```
with open('a.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: Please include the actual error and your code

Comment: Ok.  Please include the code you are using and some information about what you are trying to write to the files.  If you are trying to write a large amount of data, you may have to write it in chunks at a time

Comment: File size is of 450KB, could you let me know the performance differences between python file write and redis cache, sorry I cannot share my code, I updated sample code

Comment: The default buffering for text files with `open` is line buffering. Is your data text that is broken up into lines? If each line is too long then the buffering won't help you.  You can specify the buffer size as a keyword argument https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not sharing the details of the exception, this will have to be guesswork...

```
with open('a.txt', 'w') as f:
```

opens the file in text mode, with an implicit `encoding="utf-8"` argument. Files opened in text mode only allow writing text `str`ings, not binary `bytes`.

I assume you're getting some sort of error to that degree writing `data`, which I'll assume is `bytes` in there. (Opening the file in `"wb"` binary mode will fix that.)

Redis, on the other hand, doesn't know about text - all strings you put in Redis are just bytestrings, and you'll need to deal with encoding and decoding yourself. This is why sending your `data` bytes in works. Depending on your Redis library, it may "helpfully" encode regular text strings to UTF-8 first too.